# html template not loading: Could not find a part of the path '/Helpers/Email/Templates/template.html'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working with a .Net Core 2.1 Web Api.

I'm using 4 projects for this solution. I'm trying to load an html template, in local works fine, but once I push it in a Linux server the file can not be loaded due this error:

> html template not loading: Could not find a part of the path
>   '/Helpers/Email/Templates/template.html'

The solution's structure is the next (including folders and html file):

```
- Core
- Helpers
   - Email
     EMailHelper.cs
     - Templates
       template.html
 - Infrastructure
 - WebApi (this is the main project, with appsettings.json, ...)
```

Well, when I'm trying to load the "template.html" from "EmailHelper.cs", in local works fine either Windows and Mac, but when I upload it to the publish environment (Azure - Linux), it always throws the previous exception.

the "template.html" file has "copy at the same directory" and set as "content" as build action.

Tried also loading the file with these urls:

```
const string htmlTemplate = "../Helpers/Email/Templates/template.html";
```

and

```
string emailTemplateUserRegistration = string.Format("..{0}Helpers{0}Email{0}Templates{0}{template.html}", Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

but there is no way to load it.

Do you know which is the reason of this? how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Strange, if I load this url can't load the file from the project:

> /home/project/backend/Helpers/Email/Templates/template.html

but with vi, open the file:

> vi /home/project/backend/Helpers/Email/Templates/template.html

The method to load the file is the next:

```
 var builder = new StringBuilder();

 using (var reader = File.OpenText(htmlTemplate))
 {
      builder.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

I have to say I forgot to mention we are using Docker in Azure.

So the problem was when you publish your app, all files are located in a folder defined in docker config, i.e.:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
```

So in /app folder, all resource files are copied into, so instead of having this url:

> /home/project/backend/Helpers/Email/Templates/template.html

It has:

> /app/Email/Templates/template.html

So changing this url at my "htmlTemplate" variable, is working fine:

```
const string templateUrl = @"Email/Templates/template.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are using the wrong root Path at run time in your Azure environment. Try getting the path from the HostingEnviroment using dependency injection.

```
public class MyController{

MyController(IHostingEnvironment env){

var path = env.ContentRootPath;
var myTemplatePath = path + "/Helpers/Email/Templates/template.html"

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but still not work. In fact, is strange, because I hardcoded the absolute dir and still didn't work:

`/home/backend/Project/Helpers/Email/Templates/template.html`

but if I open this file with Vi, it opens:

`vi /home/backend/Project/Helpers/Email/Templates/template.html`

So I don't know what's going on...

Comment: Are you using webapps or just running a vm in azure?

Comment: is running a vm in Azure

Comment: Have you tried logging the path when it's running on the server? Check where it's actually pointing by writing to console or something simple

Comment: Yes, tried, it returns the same as I put in the constant variable. That's why is strange, with the same url returning from the server works with vi, but not from File.Open

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code that worked for me when deploying to AWS ECS:

```
var buildDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var htmlBase = File.ReadAllText(buildDir + @"/Email/Templates/Base.html");
```

I made sure Base.html and any other html files were:

- **Build Action**: None
- **Copy to Output Directory**: Copy Always (Copy if newer would probably also work)

Finally, when I first deployed I used back slashes instead:

```
var htmlBase = File.ReadAllText(buildDir + @"\Email\Templates\Base.html");
```

This works fine on windows, but fails in a Linux environment.

After changing to forward slashes everything worked fine.